# groovy compile error

Tags: groovy

```
class x{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String x="<html><head></head></html>";
    String arr[]=x.split("<head>");
    String script="hi";
    x=arr[0]+"<head>"+script+arr[1];
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

the above code when compiled as a java file compiles fine but when used a s a groovy file spits the error :

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
D:\Garage\groovy-binary-1.7.1\groovy-1.7.1\bin\x.groovy: 4: Apparent variable 'a
rr' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static fi
eld or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable fro
m a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelli
ng.
You attempted to use a method 'arr' but left out brackets in a place not allowed
 by the grammar.
 @ line 4, column 10.
                String arr[]=x.split("");
            ^

D:\Garage\groovy-binary-1.7.1\groovy-1.7.1\bin\x.groovy: 6: Apparent variable 'a
rr' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static fi
eld or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable fro
m a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelli
ng.
You attempted to use a method 'arr' but left out brackets in a place not allowed
 by the grammar.
 @ line 6, column 5.
                x=arr[0]+""+script+arr[1];
       ^

D:\Garage\groovy-binary-1.7.1\groovy-1.7.1\bin\x.groovy: 6: Apparent variable 'a
rr' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static fi
eld or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable fro
m a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelli
ng.
You attempted to use a method 'arr' but left out brackets in a place not allowed
 by the grammar.
 @ line 6, column 28.
                x=arr[0]+""+script+arr[1];
                              ^

3 errors

D:\Garage\groovy-binary-1.7.1\groovy-1.7.1\bin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you move the [] to the String side like so:

```
String[] arr = x.split("<head>");
```